# Convert timestamp to date in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

How can I convert 2020-12-14T18:24:27.000Z to 12/14/2020 in Google Sheets?

The Format > Number > Date command does not change the timestamp to a date.

The conversion can occcur in-place or a separate column.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can extract the date portion of the timestamp using `MID()` then use `DATEVALUE()` to convert it to date format.

```
=DATEVALUE(MID(A1,1,10))
```

Then use Format > Number > Date command.

[image]

References:

[MID()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094129?hl=en)

[DATEVALUE()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093039?hl=en)